# Use existing CMake library in a new project including its headers

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I'm working on a project where I have an existing CMake library (https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOEM) stored in `project/lib/SOEM/`.

The source for my application lives in `project/src/`

I have a root `CMakeLists.txt` which adds both subdirectories.

Now my question is how do I link the SOEM library to my executable **and** also use its headers without relative paths?

SOEM contains its own `CMakeLists.txt` which I would **preferably** not touch at all if that's possible. It builds a library and installs it together with its headers, however, I don't know how to make use of the latter.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules")
project(SOEM C)

if (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
  # Default to installing in SOEM source directory
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/install)
endif()

set(SOEM_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR include/soem)

if(WIN32)
  set(OS "win32")
  include_directories(oshw/win32/wpcap/Include)
  link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/oshw/win32/wpcap/Lib)
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}  /WX")
  set(OS_LIBS wpcap.lib Packet.lib Ws2_32.lib Winmm.lib)
elseif(UNIX)
  set(OS "linux")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Werror")
  set(OS_LIBS pthread rt)
elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "rt-kernel")
  set(OS "rtk")
  message("ARCH is ${ARCH}")
  message("BSP is ${BSP}")
  include_directories(oshw/${OS}/${ARCH})
  file(GLOB OSHW_EXTRA_SOURCES oshw/${OS}/${ARCH}/*.c)
  set(OSHW_SOURCES "${OS_HW_SOURCES} ${OSHW_ARCHSOURCES}")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Werror")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-unused-but-set-variable")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-unused-function")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-format")
  set(OS_LIBS "-Wl,--start-group -l${BSP} -l${ARCH} -lkern -ldev -lsio -lblock -lfs -lusb -llwip -leth -li2c -lrtc -lcan -lnand -lspi -lnor -lpwm -ladc -ltrace -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group")
endif()

message("OS is ${OS}")

file(GLOB SOEM_SOURCES soem/*.c)
file(GLOB OSAL_SOURCES osal/${OS}/*.c)
file(GLOB OSHW_SOURCES oshw/${OS}/*.c)

file(GLOB SOEM_HEADERS soem/*.h)
file(GLOB OSAL_HEADERS osal/osal.h osal/${OS}/*.h)
file(GLOB OSHW_HEADERS oshw/${OS}/*.h)

include_directories(soem)
include_directories(osal)
include_directories(osal/${OS})
include_directories(oshw/${OS})

add_library(soem STATIC
  ${SOEM_SOURCES}
  ${OSAL_SOURCES}
  ${OSHW_SOURCES}
  ${OSHW_EXTRA_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(soem ${OS_LIBS})

install(TARGETS soem DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES
  ${SOEM_HEADERS}
  ${OSAL_HEADERS}
  ${OSHW_HEADERS}
  DESTINATION ${SOEM_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR})

add_subdirectory(test/linux/slaveinfo)
add_subdirectory(test/linux/eepromtool)
add_subdirectory(test/linux/simple_test)
```

Comment: As root `CMakeLists.txt` knows source directory of SOEM project, it may pass this directory to your subproject (e.g. via setting a variable). Then your project may compute location or the SOEM headers. As for SOEM library, you may link with it using **target** name.

Comment: @Tsyvarev could you perhaps give a simple working example? I'm quite new to CMake

Comment: Something like `set(SOEM_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/SOEM)` in root `CMakeLists.txt` (assuming you have `add_subdirectory(lib/SOEM)` in it). Then, in `src/CMakeLists.txt` use `include_directories(${SOEM_DIR}/soem)` - such a way, `#include <...>` will work for headers in `soem/` directory. Analogue command is needed for headers from other directories.

Comment: Note, that in your current approach, *installed* SOEM files are not accessible at the time your project is built. If you want to work with installed SOEM files, you need to install SOEM first. (Withing `CMakeLists.txt` this can be achieved by using [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html) instead of `add_subdirectory(lib/SOEM)`).